# Command-line OCR in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, software-rec, 64-bit, ocr

What are some command-line OCR utilities that will work in Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: For Linux/OSX, check: [OCR on Linux systems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548/ocr-on-linux-systems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is the best (free) command-line based OCR software. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a Windows 7 64-bit binary available so you'd have to compile it yourself; here are the instructions for doing so (taken from a comment on the [Tesseract FAQ page](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ)):

> 1. Download tesseract 2.04. Unpack it. In this example I've unpacked to
>      C:\projects\tesseract-2.04. Windows 7
>      still doesn't understand .tar.gz out
>      of the box. My recommendation is to
>      get a copy of 7-Zip.
> 2. Download your required language files. I need German and English. I
>      unpack these to the tessdata
>      subdirectory of
>      C:\projects\tesseract-2.04\tessdata.
> 3. Install libtiff. On my (64 bit) system the suggested install directory
>      is C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32?.
>      Underneath this directory are a bunch
>      of subdirectories containing files
>      we'll need to compile tesseract with
>      tiff support, namely include, bin and
>      lib.
> 4. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32?\bin to your PATH
>      environment variable so that the
>      output tesseract.exe can find the
>      libtiff dll. Restart.
> 5. Open the vc solution (tesseract.sln)
> 6. Change the solution configuration to "Release" mode. Note that if you
>      later change back to Debug mode,
>      you'll need to set up all the
>      following again...
> 7. In the solution explorer right click the solution node (Solution
>      'tesseract') and click "Properties".
>      Change to "Configuration Properties"
>      and select "Release" configuration
>      from the dropdown at the top of the
>      window. Navigate to: Tools -> Options
>      -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories Here we'll be adding the
>      full paths for the subdirectories lib
>      and include from the libtiff install
>      so that VC can find the required
>      header (.h) and static library (.lib)
>      files. In this example they are:
>      $(ProgramFiles?)\GnuWin32?\include
>      $(ProgramFiles?)\GnuWin32?\lib as I'm
>      using an environment variable. I could
>      however just have written them as
>      C:\Program Files
>      (x86)\GnuWin32?\include.
>      Change the "Show Directories For"
>      dropdown to "Include files". Add the
>      following:
>      $(ProgramFiles?)\GnuWin32?\include
>      Now change the "Show Directories For"
>      dropdown to "Library files". Add the
>      following:
>      $(ProgramFiles?)\GnuWin32?\lib
> 8. Now open the project properties window for the tesseract project (not
>      the solution). In the solution
>      explorer right click the tesseract
>      project and click properties. Navigate
>      the horrendous list of options to
>      Configuration Properties -> C/C++ ->
>      Preprocessor and add HAVE_LIBTIFF to
>      the list of Preprocessor Definitions.
>      This causes a bunch of #includes to be
>      enabled in the code.
> 9. You also want to add an "Additional dependency". go to the "Additional
>      dependencies" section for the project
>      properties and add libtiff.lib.
> 10. Build the solution. Watch the error list. If you get a bunch of
>       LNK2109 errors, that means the linker
>       can't find something tesseract
>       references. You're missing a reference
>       to one of the paths from libtiff. If
>       you get an error mentioning mt.exe,
>       you've possibly encountered a bug in
>       the sdk. Just try building again. see
>       http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=106634
>       for more info.
>
> If/when the solution builds
>   successfully, you'll have a
>   tesseract.exe file in the same
>   directory as the tesseract solution
>   file. drag you multipage compressed
>   tiff here and try running tesseract.
>   for example, if your tiff is called
>   in.tif and you want to output text to
>   out.txt, and the documents' language
>   is German then your command line would
>   look like:
>
> tesseract.exe in.tif out -l deu The
>   output file will have .txt appended to
>   it by tesseract. If you're just
>   translating English text then you can
>   leave off the -l option, as tesseract
>   assumes "eng" if you don't specify
>   anything. If your tif file has the
>   file extension .tiff, then tesseract
>   will crap itself thusly:
>
> C:\projects\tesseract-2.04>tesseract.exe
>   in.tiff out -l deu Tesseract Open
>   Source OCR Engine
>   name_to_image_type:Error:Unrecognized
>   image type:in.tiff
>   IMAGE::read_header:Error:Can't read
>   this image type:in.tiff
>   tesseract.exe:Error:Read of file
>   failed:in.tiff
>
> Hopefully (fingers crossed, heh)
>   you've now got an OCR'd out.txt file
>   sitting in C:\projects\tesseract-2.04.

Answer (score 1):

JOCR is the only one I know which can work on windows and is command-line based.  View their webpage [here](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an installer for windows 7 for tesseract. I have just installed it and got it to do OCR on a small image. The result was terrible but I hope with some tuning I can improve the results.